# Cron job creating output file, but not running Python script

Tags: linux, python, cron

I have the following entry in crontab -e, which is supposed to run a python script every day at 11 am and dump the output to log.txt:

`0 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/folder/python/script.py > /var/www/folder/python/logs/log.txt`

The log.txt file is being consistently created, but nothing is being written to it. As far as I can tell, the python script is not being run at all despite working correctly when run from the terminal directly.

Is there something wrong with my cron syntax or is it something else I could be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Since `/var/www/folder/python/logs/log.txt` is being created, that means the shell redirection is occurring as you would expect, so it does seem to be executing the command, albeit unsuccessfully.
You can have it send its `stderr` to the log as well by modifying your cron entry to:

```
0 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/folder/python/script.py > /var/www/folder/python/logs/log.txt 2>&1
```

You might want to check `/var/mail/$USER` as well; there might be informative `stderr` output there if it's behaving differently than when you run `/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/folder/python/script.py` manually.